# Can't remove new elements in Eclipse toolbar

Tags: eclipse, user-interface, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-cdt

[image: [Eclipse Toolbar]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9u90W.png)

I installed the Eclipse CDT the other day and when i restarted Eclipse my toolbar was updated to show several new (but useless) buttons on the top left hand corner of the toolbar. I've looked in my toolbar customization to try to remove the buttons (bigger build button, launch button, stop button, and the dropdown menus) but I can't seem to find it in there. Is it a plug-in and if so, how do I remove it?

Answer (score 21):

### What is it

That is the new Launch Bar. It is a new feature for CDT that will hopefully be adopted in the future by the platform. The version you have installed is an earlier preview build. Eclipse Neon will have a newer version.

### How to turn it off

Go to *Windows* -> *Preferences* -> *Run/Debug* -> *Launching* -> *Launch Bar* and uncheck *Enable the Launch Bar*

Here is a screen shot:

[image: screenshot]

### Try it out

Now that you know how to enable/disable it, I can recommend you try it out. [It is being improved and polished](http://cdtdoug.ca/2016/02/10/launchbar-and-user-experience/), and many people who have tried it out for a while have found that it improves their workflow.

Comment: Thanks! I thought it might have had something to do with installing CDT

Comment: @Matthieu not very likely as OP has "Last seen Nov 22 '16 at 8:19" on profile.

Comment: @JonahGraham just in case the email notification triggered a sudden will to finish the job... :)

Answer (score -1):

If you think those buttons are contributed by eclipse CDT plugins. You can go and remove them by following approach.

Follow these instructions/menu options: 
**Eclipse -> About Eclipse -> Installation Details -> Installed Software tab -> you might find something with Eclipse CDT -> select that -> Click on Uninstall button from below**

After uninstallation, restart the eclipse